# Test Case for Weighted Reservoir Sampling

Tags: machine-learning, probability, cloudera, sampling, reservoir-sampling

I need to implement Weighted Reservoir Sampling. I have referred to the paper mentioned in this [blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/hadoop-stratified-randosampling-algorithm/). I want to write test-cases for unit testing my implementation and am confused as to how to calculate expected-probability of different element to be in reservoir.

I thought it should be propotional to `(weight_of_element/weight_of_all_elements)`, but the test-case mentioned [here](https://github.com/cloudera/ml/blob/master/parallel/src/test/java/com/cloudera/science/ml/parallel/sample/ReservoirSamplingTest.java) computes it differently. How should I do it?

Comment: The expected probability for every element should be equal, correct? What is the problem you are running into? Are you confused about the sampling process?

Comment: @eigenchris this is not "reservoir sampling" but "weighted reservoir sampling", so it should be propotional to weights of the element. But in the test-cases, expected values don't correspond to that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a test-case, you can indeed estimate the probability of the element being chosen. Suppose you've assigned weights like this:
**weights = [1, 5, 8, 2, 5]**

Now you are doing Weighted Reservoir Sampling in order to draw **one** element. What are the probabilities of element appearing in the result? They are exactly `(weight_of_element/weight_of_all_elements)`:
**prob = [0.048, 0.238, 0.381, 0.095, 0.238]**

In other words, if you draw one element repeatedly 10<sup>6</sup> times, you should have 0.381 * 10<sup>6</sup> instances of the third element, 0.048 *   10<sup>6</sup> instances of the first element, and so on. **Approximately**, of course.

Therefore, you can look at the percentage of times the first element appeared out of 10<sup>6</sup> trials. This must be approximately `(weight_of_first_element/weight_of_all_elements)`. Compare those values and see if they are close to each other.

So the test-case may look like this (pseudo-code):

```
numTrials = 1000000
histogram = map<int, int>
for i = 1..numTrials:
  element = WeightedReservoir.sample(weights, 1) # draw one element
  histogram[element]++
for i = 1..len(weights):
  real_probability = weights[i] / sum(weights)
  observed_probability = histogram[elements[i]] / numTrials
  assert(abs(real_probability - observed_probability) <= epsilon) # measuring absolute difference, but you can switch to relative difference
```

See [this](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/issues/80#issuecomment-31486893) thread for specific implementation in Java.

As for Cloudera [test](https://github.com/cloudera/ml/blob/master/parallel/src/test/java/com/cloudera/science/ml/parallel/sample/ReservoirSamplingTest.java) you've pointed out, it follows different logic (I've seen this in Python package **numpy** tests for numpy.random.choice as well):

1. The sampling routine is probabilistic in its nature, i.e. **non-deterministic**;
2. Let's take a fixed seed value for random number generation. Embed this value into test-case. Now it is fully deterministic: invoking the test-case several times yields **the same result**;
3. Since the result is deterministic, we can obtain it **manually** (for small inputs). Embed the expected result into test.

If you cannot control the seed value, this method is not for you.